# OCI8 em PHP 7.0 com Xampp 32bit

Tags: php, oracle, xampp

Estou usando o xampp no windows 7,  versão do PHP é a 7.0.15. Instalei o Oracle Instant Client (32bits tbm) e em seguida extraí na pasta "ext" do php a versão 2.1.3 do OCI8 de acordo com este site (https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.1.3/windows). O problema é que depois de fazer todo o processo, no phpinfo() não exibe a seção do OCI8, logo, ele não está conectado/instalado de fato. Desde já agradeço!

Como está no php.ini: 
extension=php_oci8_12c.dll ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client

Mensagem quando ponho o comando "php -m":

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o m¾dulo especificado.
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_12c.dll' - NÒo foi possÝvel encontrar o m¾dulo especificado.
 in Unknown on line 0
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Depois de extrar a DLL na pasta ext, você habilitou isso no seu php.ini ? Após alterar o php.ini, reiniciou o apache?

Comment: Fiz tudo isso sim. Com a versão 5.6.30 do PHP no quando eu iniciava o apache (após habilitar a dll no php.ini) ficava exibindo uma mensagem como se não fosse possível ler a dll. Ah e também quando tento instalar o OCI8 no terminal pelo pecl exibe uma um "erro: the dsp oci8.dsp does not exist.

Comment: Você está usando a versão 5.6 do php? Porque este link que você passou acima é exclusivo do php 7.

Comment: Não não, estou usando o PHP 7. Agora que vi devo ter apagado a parte que mencionava que eu também tinha tentado com a versão 5.6.30. Mas atualmente estou com a versão 7.

Comment: poderia postar a parte do seu php.ini que está habilitando a extensão?

Comment: Está assim e descomentei o ";": extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client

Comment: Poderia editar sua pergunta e colocar o código formatado?

Comment: No caso, a imagem do php.ini?

Comment: Não. Por favor edite a sua pergunta e adicione a parte do php.ini que contem a configuração da extensão OCI8

Comment: Pronto, editado

Comment: Poderia me dizer o módulo é exibido da seguinte maneira: Abra um CMD, digite `php -m` ?

Comment: Editei a postagem, dá uma olhada no que apareceu. Não aparece o oci8

Comment: E pra piorar fica exibindo a mensagem que diz que está faltando php7.dll.

Comment: Pela sua mensagem de erro, ele não está encontrando o arquivo na pasta. Poderia verificar se a DLL esta na pasta e com o nome correto?

Comment: Está na mesma pasta e com o nome certo

Comment: Poderia providenciar uma screenshot contendo o nome da pasta e a DLL?

Comment: Pronto editei. Assim?

Comment: Poderia me informar se a sua versão do php é 32 ou 64 bits? E a extensão, é 32 ou 64 bits?

Comment: Desculpas a demora, passei o fim de semana sem internet. Tanto o PHP quanto a extensão são 32bits

Comment: Poderia tentar instalar a extensão listada [aqui](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.1.3/) ?

Comment: Woow, conectou com o php \o/. Agora só falta ver se consigo comunicar com o banco. Cara, muito obrigado! Já consegui avançar!

Comment: coloquei uma resposta com a solução encontrada. Se isto resolveu seu problema, por favor, marque-a como resposta correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema está relacionado a `ABI` utilizada na compilação da DLL.
É bem provavel que a DLL fornecida no PECL esteja incorreta.

Baixe a DLL correta para a sua versão do php [aqui](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.1.3/).